# Android: Lottie Animation with dynamic text and custom font issue

Tags: android, animation, android-jetpack-compose, lottie, dynamic-text

I'm trying to dynamically swap a text inside a LottieAnimation in jetpack compose.
The lottie file is exported without glyphs

It's working when using the old android view inside a

```
AndroidView(factory = { context ->
    val view = LottieAnimationView(context).apply {
        setAnimation(R.raw.testing_no_glyphs)
        playAnimation()
        repeatCount = LottieConstants.IterateForever
    }

    val textDel = object : TextDelegate(view) {
        override fun getText(layerName: String?, input: String?): String {
            return when (layerName) {
                "Test234" -> "OtherLettersHere"
                else -> super.getText(layerName, input)
            }
        }
    }

    val fontDel = object : FontAssetDelegate() {
        override fun getFontPath(fontFamily: String?, fontStyle: String?, fontName: String?): String {
            return "fonts/[MyFontInside /assets].ttf"
        }
    }

    view.setTextDelegate(textDel)
    view.setFontAssetDelegate(fontDel)
    return@AndroidView view
})
```

But I can't find the correct handles in the JetpackCompose version of Lottie to get the same result.

If we export the lottie with glyphs, it's works for the letters in the `chars` array inside the lottie json. But we want to be able to replace with any letters/symbols, so this isn't a viable solution.

I've noticed in the 5.3.0-SNAPSHOT that a `fontMap` parameter has been added, but I can't figure out which key to hit with it.

Here is my code:

```
val dynamicProperties = rememberLottieDynamicProperties(
    rememberLottieDynamicProperty(LottieProperty.TEXT, value = "AaBbCcEeFf", keyPath = arrayOf("Test234"))
)
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
    spec = LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.testing)
)
val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(composition, iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever)

LottieAnimation(
    composition,
    { progress },
    dynamicProperties = dynamicProperties,
    fontMap = mapOf("fName" to Typeface.createFromAsset(LocalContext.current.assets, "fonts/[MyFontInside /assets].ttf"))
)
```

It just shows a blank for all the texts inside the Lottie Animation - so this is kinda where i'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial an error I found a way to add the typeface for a specific layer:

```
val typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(LocalContext.current.assets, "fonts/[MyFontInside /assets].ttf")

val dynamicProperties = rememberLottieDynamicProperties(
    rememberLottieDynamicProperty(LottieProperty.TEXT, value = "AaBbCcEeFf", keyPath = arrayOf("Test234")),
--> rememberLottieDynamicProperty(LottieProperty.TYPEFACE, value = typeface, keyPath = arrayOf("Test234")),
)
```

Hence there is no need for the `fontMap` in my case

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `fontMap` field in `LottieAnimation`. In your Lottie json file you'll need to check what font families it need and provide a mapping to a `Typeface`

*`fontMap`: The key can be "fName", "fFamily", or "fFamily-fStyle" as specified in your Lottie file.*

```
val customFontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.roboto))
val resolver = LocalFontFamilyResolver.current
val typeface by remember { 

LottieAnimation(
    ...
    fontMap = mapOf(
        "Roboto-Regular" to typeface.value as Typeface
    ),
)
```

**OR**

```
val customFontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.roboto))
val resolver = LocalFontFamilyResolver.current
val typeface by remember { mutableStateOf(resolver.resolve(customFontFamily)) }

val dynamicProperties = rememberLottieDynamicProperties(
    rememberLottieDynamicProperty(
        property = LottieProperty.TYPEFACE,
        value = typeface.value,
        keyPath = arrayOf(
            "**" // or some other key path
        )
    )
)
```